# Pip has 2 versions, what should I do?

Tags: python, time, pip, pycharm, version

So i really don't know what to do. I am confused. I am also using a virtual environment named PyCharm. There are many issues with pip there but I haven't seen anything as weird as this.

cmd output:

```
C:\Users\Artur\PycharmProjects\first\venv\Scripts>pip install time
```

> Collecting time
>     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement time (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for time
>   You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

```
C:\Users\Artur\PycharmProjects\first\venv\Scripts>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\artur\pycharmprojects\first\venv\lib\site-packages (19.0.1)

```
C:\Users\Artur\PycharmProjects\first\venv\Scripts>pip install time
```

> Collecting time
>     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement time (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for time
>   You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

[image: cmd]

Comment: `time` is a built-in module of Python, are you sure that's what you want to install?

Comment: Yes, i read that it is a built-in. In PyCharm it's just not recognized. The solution should be to install it by cmd, or so i read. But the issue here is that my pip has 2 versions or something is wrong with interpreter?

Comment: Go back to “Pycharm doesn’t recognize time”. What does that mean? What are you trying to do with time that isn’t recognized?

Comment: when I am trying to import it at the begging of my code it is grayed out like there is no "time" module.

Comment: “Grayed out” in Pycharm usually means it’s *unused* and could be removed. I.e. you’ve imported it but have written no code that uses it. If it’s not found it’s typically highlighted in red.

Comment: Ohh, that's my bad then. tested it and time.sleep works just fine and "time" gets orange like it should be. Still i don't really know why the pip install time says pip is outdated when it's definitely 19.0.1

Comment: `pip` and `python -m pip` seem to be referring to two different installations in your case. Use one or the other form, don’t mix them.

Answer (score 0):

To resolving your outdated pip in PyCharm by running this in your PyCharm terminal:

```
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```

This will fix the warning you are receiving...`You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.`